# Redirect back to URL with variables

Tags: oop, laravel, routes

I'm setting up a "Do you confirm to terms and conditions?" type page with Laravel. The user has to check the box, fill in the current date and submit. The URL they are given will be something like;

```
example.com/laravel/public/security-agreement/23823jdsjdsreuyr
```

The `23823jdsjdsreuyr` part is a unique code in the table against that agreement.

My routes file;

```
Route::get('/security-agreement/{code}',  array('as' => 'security-agreement','uses' => 'SecurityAgreementController@getAgreement'));

Route::post('/security-agreement', array('as' => 'security-agreement','uses' => 'SecurityAgreementController@postAgreement'));
```

My controller;

```
public function getAgreement($code) {
  $client_agreement = ClientAgreement::with('agreements')->where('code', '=', $code)->first();
  $client = ClientAgreement::with('clients')->where('code', '=', $code)->first();

  return View::make('contracts.index')
  ->with('client_agreement', $client_agreement)
  ->with('client', $client);
}

public function postAgreement() {
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'start_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
    'accept' => 'required|accepted'
    ));

  if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::route('security-agreement')
      ->withErrors($validator);
  } else {
     print "success";
  }

}
```

My question is... How do I return the user if they have made errors (if validator fails), and keep the code in the URL? I'm not married to this way of doing it if there is a better way. I just needed a way of making the lookup id unguessable.

I've tried a few different ways of playing around with the routes and also concatenating `$code` at the `Redirect::route` point but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Redirect::route()` takes a second parameter that would coincide with the variables you have set on the route, so in `postAgreement()`, you'd want to do something like `return Redirect::route('security-agreement', array($code));` and that would redirect the user back to that route with the code properly set in the URL.

If you do no not have the code in that route, you would probably want to add it as a route variable or even a hidden input on the page so you can grab it via `Input::get('code')`.

You may also be able to use just `return Redirect::back()` and that should redirect the user back to the last page.

Comment: I couldn't get your first suggestion to work for some reason. I'd just be updating the controller, right? `Redirect::back()` did the trick though. I'll use that.

Comment: It *may* have something to do with having two routes with the same name.  The only problem I've had with `Redirect::back()` is it seems a bit harder to test, so I usually stick with `Redirect::route()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Route::post('/security-agreement/{code}', array('as' => 'security-agreement','uses' => 'SecurityAgreementController@postAgreement'));

public function postAgreement($code) {
  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
    'start_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
    'accept' => 'required|accepted'
  ));

  if($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::route('security-agreement', $code)
      ->withErrors($validator);
  } else {
     print "success";
  }
}
```